# elasticsearch.yml missing

Tags: server, search, elasticsearch

Apparently, Elasticsearch causes my server to crash sometimes.

So I wanted to follow the instructions provided by Binh_Ly here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/garbage-collection-log-messages-monitor-jvm-duration-2-2m/15673

But he says to change the elasticsearch.yml, which should be in the /etc/elasticsearch folder according to the official elasticsearch website. But neither the file nor the folder do exist and can't even be found when I look for them with `find / -name elasticsearch -type d`, it only shows me the elasticsearch folder where the data lies, but no other elasticsearch folders.

Would it make sense to just create a new folder? (I'm sorry, I don't have that much experience.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Elasticsearch page setting section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-configuration.html#settings), `elasticsearch.yml` file can be found on `ES_HOME/config` folder.

> **elasticsearch** configuration files can be found under `ES_HOME/config`folder. The folder comes with two files, the **`elasticsearch.yml`** for configuring Elasticsearch different modules, and `logging.yml` for configuring the Elasticsearch logging.

If you have really look anywhere and come on the situation where `elasticsearch.yml` file missing, then you'll probably interested on creating new one.

Luckily someone has posted content of `elasticsearch.yml` on GitHub Gist, you may want to look at this [`elasticsearch.yml - GitHub`](https://gist.github.com/zsprackett/8546403).

Answer (score 0):

**Using Ubuntu 20.0.4**:

I had the same problem but in my case I did not use `sudo` at the beginning of search command. I was searching for the file in the `/etc` folder using the following command: `find /etc -type f -iname "elasticsearch*"`

I got this:

```
find: ‘/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/elasticsearch’: Permission denied
/etc/default/elasticsearch
find: ‘/etc/polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/cups/ssl’: Permission denied
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch
```

But I forgot to use `sudo`, so I was logged in as only a user account without root privileges.

When I tried again as `root` by putting `sudo`, I found the file:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -iname "elasticsearch*"
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
/etc/default/elasticsearch
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch
```